# Robust keyboard shortcut handling using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

What's the most robust way of creating a global keyboard shortcut handler for a Web application using JavaScript i.e. which event(s) should I handle and what should the event handler(s) be attached to?

I want something like the system in Gmail which can handle both single keypress shortcuts and also shortcuts with modifier keys e.g. Ctrl + B etc. The code has to work in IE 6 as well as modern browsers.

I have the Prototype framework available to use but not jQuery, so please, no jQuery-specific answers!

Comment: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HotKey library available in the LivePipe controls package works with Prototype and is IE compatible.

http://livepipe.net/extra/hotkey

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because this looks like exactly what I'm looking for and because there's lots of other interesting stuff on that site, so thanks!

Comment: Be warned, HotKey apparently accepts combinations if unspecified modifiers are pressed (eg. specified ctrl + a, pressed ctrl + shift + a, the ctrl + a is detected).

Comment: It would also be nice if it detected OS X and replaced ctrl with cmd/meta.

Answer (score 6):

Just thought I'd throw another into the mix.  I recently released a library called Mousetrap.  Check it out at http://craig.is/killing/mice

Answer (score 4):

JimmyP posted this as a comment, but it deserves to be an answer for voting purposes.

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: I know, that's why I asked him why he hadn't posted it as an answer. Upvoted.

Comment: I know, that's why I posted it as an answer. ;) And I posted it community wiki because it's not my points to earn.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is attach onKeyUp events to the document.body. Then, in this event handler, I would use the [Element.fire](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/fire) method to fire a custom event. Though this step is optional, it will help in decoupling the event handler from the action to be performed, and you can use the same custom-event handler from say an button click event.

```
$(document.body).observe("keyup", function() {
    if(/* key + modifier match */) {
        $(document.body).fire("myapp:mycoolevent");
    }
});

$(document.body).observe("myapp:mycoolevent", function() {
    // Handle event.
});
```

Later, to bind the same event to a button click:

```
$(button).observe("click", function() {
    $(document.body).fire("myapp:mycoolevent");
});
```

As far as handling modifier keys is concerned, check out [this resource](http://www.webreference.com/js/column11/modifierkeys.html) (very old, but still looks applicable) for more help.

Comment: Keyup seems problematic. At least on OS X (but I believe it's true on Windows and most Linux WMs as well), most key commands activate on keydown. This expectation (with proper checking) also enforces certain expectations on shortcuts: modifier keys must be first, only one printable key per shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

There is also new JavaScript library called [jwerty](https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/), it's easy to use and doesn't rely on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at [Keystrokes](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes#readme). It makes this sort of thing extremely easy.

```js
import { bindKey, bindKeyCombo } from '@rwh/keystrokes'

bindKey('a', () =>
  console.log('You\'re pressing "a"'))

bindKeyCombo('ctrl > y, r', () =>
  console.log('You pressed "ctrl" then "y", released both, and are pressing "r"'))
```